# Fields in response object from fetch method are undefined

Tags: javascript, async-await, cloudflare-workers

I am trying to write a cloudflare worker script for a take-home challenge. I need to fetch the given url stored in `urls` var in my script which will give a json array of two urls. I need to make a fetch request to one of the urls in the array, here the code I wrote

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})
/**
 * Respond with urls
 * @param {Request} request
 */
async function handleRequest(request) {

  var urls= await fetch('https://cfw-takehome.developers.workers.dev/api/variants')

 .then(function(res){

   return res;
})
var first=await urls.variants[0];
 return first;
}
```

And this is the JSON the  `urls` variable conatains

```
{"variants":["https://cfw-takehome.developers.workers.dev/variants/1","https://cfw-takehome.developers.workers.dev/variants/2"]}
```

but I see that when I try to access the first object in the array, it is undefined as I get this error

```
Uncaught (in response) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Please help me find the cause of this and suggest a solution. I am guessing I am failing to understand some concept about asynchronous Javascript here.

Comment: Are u sure that u don't have cors problem ?

Comment: I get this error if I try your approach ```TypeError: Failed to execute function: parameter 1 is not of type 'Response'```

Answer (score 0):

You made few mistakes here:

- First one is that you need to return `res.json()` instead of just `res`, because response object returned from `fetch` is not the actual response and needs to be serialized.
- Second one is that you don't need another `await` as it will create unnecessary promise.

So here is the correct functions code:

```
async function handleRequest() {
    var urls = await fetch('https://cfw-takehome.developers.workers.dev/api/variants')
     .then(res => res.json()) // res.json() instead just res
    var first = urls.variants[0]; // await removed
    return first;
}
```

Comment: tried that...I get this error ```Uncaught (in response) TypeError: Failed to execute function: parameter 1 is not of type 'Response' ```

Comment: This code works if I run it from console while I am on that web-page (cfw-takehome).

Comment: Do you by any chance know why I might get that error stated in above comment? I can't seem to debug it

Answer (score 0):

I have tried above and only change that required is return newResponse.

```
async function handleRequest() {
    var urls = await fetch('https://cfw-takehome.developers.workers.dev/api/variants')
     .then(response => response.json())
    var first = urls.variants[0];
    return new Response(first);
}
```